# Error passing jinga url template to javascript function

Tags: javascript, django, jinja2

I am trying to run the following javascript function

```
<script>
    function getForm(id, element, url_route) {
        console.log(id, element, url_route)
    }
</script>
```

within

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getForm('login-form', 'login-authentication', '{% url 'accounts:password_reset' %}');">Login</a>
```

Clearly there is a problem with the quotations in `'{% url 'accounts:password_reset' %}'`. I have tried various different approaches to escape the quotations but the webserver still throws out an error. I have tried the following but still unsuccessful:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getForm('login-form', 'login-authentication', '{% url \'accounts:password_reset\' %}');">Login</a>
```

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getForm('login-form', 'login-authentication', '{% url &quot;accounts:password_reset&quot; %}');">Login</a>
```

I have also tried to build the url directly from the javascript function but it also doesn't work.

```
var url = 'accounts:password_reset';
console.log('{% url "' + url + '" %}');
```

The urls.py file looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
path('password_reset/', views.password_reset, name="password_reset"),
]
```

Comment: could you add your urls.py content? I need to know your url names.

Comment: Edited question with the info

Comment: I tested a code likes yours, using `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getForm('login-form', 'login-authentication', '{% url 'accounts:password_reset' %}');">Login</a>` it is working properly on me. I am using python 3.10 and django 4.1.6

Comment: Yes it is working for me now also. It is strange since VS Code highlights it as an error even though it does work. I will probably have to search for a linter to handle that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you should be able to pass `'{% url 'accounts:password_reset' %}'` directly into your javascript function's parameters. If you are seeing errors within VS Code then you can mute them by editing the `settings.json` with `"html.validate.scripts": false`